# Invalid ConnectionString format for parameter "Version 3"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I have created the object & also provided with the connection string (not sure whether it is accurate or not).
I am using  ado.net 2.0/3.5 provider for sqlite in c#.

```
SQLiteTransaction trans;
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = pathology.db ; Version 3";
con.Open();
trans = con.BeginTransaction();
int retval = 0;
```

After running above code I am getting invalid connection string format for parameter Version 3 on `con.Open();` .

Need some guidance on it as I m a beginner using visual studio  c# & sqlite.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `Version=3;`. Also you might need to specify full path to db file.

There is good site for connection strings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: Got it. db file is in debug folder so it is working  without providing the full path.